# Reducing null check in free marker templete

Tags: freemarker

I have json:

```
{"getKycBusinessDetailsResponse": 
  {"ADDRESS": 
    {"fieldDataResponse":
      {  "dataValue": 
          {"__type": "com.amazon.skies#AddressData", 
           "addressId": "2BH6RKV6KLU4OAFIQGOEG12IX7FW7W7I6A2H6I7W7WF7XILPXTQ2EIA2OX4BY72H"},
         "isEditable": false, 
       "isMandatory": false, 
       "isUpdateRequired": false}, 
     "fieldDocumentsResponse": 
      {"documentValue": 
        {}, 
       "isMandatory": false, 
       "isUpdateRequired": false}
    }
  }
}
```

I want extract the addressId value from the above Json and this what I have done:

```
<#if getKYCBusinessData??>
    <#assign getKYCBusinessData = (getKYCBusinessData)?eval>
    <#if getKYCBusinessData.getKycBusinessDetailsResponse?? && getKYCBusinessData.getKycBusinessDetailsResponse?has_content>
        <#assign businessDetails = getKYCBusinessData.getKycBusinessDetailsResponse>
        <#if businessDetails.ADDRESS?? && businessDetails.ADDRESS?has_content>
            <#assign ADDRESS = businessDetails.ADDRESS>
            <#if ADDRESS.fieldDataResponse?? && ADDRESS.fieldDataResponse?has_content>
                <#assign fieldDataResponse = ADDRESS.fieldDataResponse>
                <#if fieldDataResponse.dataValue?? && fieldDataResponse.dataValue?has_content>
                    <#assign dataValue = fieldDataResponse.dataValue>
                    <#if dataValue.addressId?? && dataValue.addressId?has_content>
                        <#assign addressId = dataValue.addressId>
                            {
                                "addressId" : "${addressId}"
                            }
                    </#if>
                </#if>
            </#if>
        </#if>
    </#if>
</#if>
```

As you can see here to extract the address id there are multiple null check need to apply. How do reduce the number of null check here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key is to know about the `(...)!` construct, which makes an `[]` (and also an `""` and `false` on the same time, but we don't utilize that) out of the expression inside, if that fails due to a missing variable. What makes the solution still verbose is that you only need the `{ ... }` in the output if the thing printed inside it exits. To deal with that, I treat the result as a list that's either 0 or 1 long:

```
<#list ([ getKYCBusinessData.getKycBusinessDetailsResponse.ADDRESS
          .fieldDataResponse.dataValue.addressId ])! as it>
   {
      "addressId": "${it}"
   }
</#list>
```

Another approach is to `#assign` and do an `#if`, however, it can't tell the difference between a value that was truly missing, and a value that was there but had a value like `""`:

```
<#assign opt = (getKYCBusinessData.getKycBusinessDetailsResponse.ADDRESS
                  .fieldDataResponse.dataValue.addressId)!>
<#if opt?has_content>
   {
      "addressId": "${opt}"
   }
</#if>
```